# store kend grid data to data base

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to store a grid data to a table in database.

Grid which i use is Kendo Grid
//View

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<OnlineAB.Models.Sales>()
.Name("SalesGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Resource).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Customer).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.GS).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Price).Width(150);
})
.Sortable()
)
```

Can anyone help me in how to store these column values to a database. When we click an "Save" button. This action is to be performed.

And also i want to add "DropDown Box" in the Column Customer. That dropdown will hold a set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the kendo official site's demo. I can help you if you leave the server side wrapper & wish to use httm 5. I did this sort of things recently.

Comment: Server wrapper isn't free, you have to pay $999 for this, so make sure you really want to use that!